# how to paginate combined with anchor id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and learning while trying to fix some bugs on my company website. I'm trying to paginate a collection of records combined with a particular anchor, i.e. when user clicks on the next/previous page, the pagination happens and user lands on a particular section of the page. This is how my code looks at the moment:

### view

```
<%= page_navigation_links @student_logs, :page %></p>
```

### controller:

```
@student_logs.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

### application_helper

```
def page_navigation_links(pages, param_name=:page)

  will_paginate(pages, :class => 'pagination', :inner_window => 2, :outer_window => 0, :renderer => BootstrapHelper::LinkRenderer, :previous_label => '&larr;'.html_safe, :next_label => '&rarr;'.html_safe, :param_name => param_name)

end
```

This works fine for my pagination, but I need to fit a reference to an 'anchor id' into this code, like Student Logs, so that when user navigates to a different page the browser navigates the user to the heading with id: "student_logs".

I can't figure out how to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not have direct experience with it. However, [this link](http://pastebin.com/6sS728bx) shows a way. I could not test but you can certainly do.

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :params => {:anchor => i} %>
```

If this works, then you can utilize this way in your helper:

```
def page_navigation_links(pages, param_name=:page)
  will_paginate(pages, :params => {:anchor => "#ANCHOR"}, :class => 'pagination', :inner_window => 2, :outer_window => 0, :renderer => BootstrapHelper::LinkRenderer, :previous_label => '&larr;'.html_safe, :next_label => '&rarr;'.html_safe, :param_name => param_name)
end
```

You can replace `#ANCHOR` as you need.

Comment: That worked nicely! Thanks to HungryCoder. There's still a little But though, my browser navigates at slightly below the anchor reference, don't know why. I'm using id attribute to refer to my anchor element.